# How to find MS C/C++ compilers in Appveyor

Tags: appveyor

I need to find Microsoft's compiler, cl.exe, for my project's build test, but can't seem to find it in the Visual Studio 15 image.  I've looked at many github hosted appveyor.yml files for inspiration (like https://github.com/frankmorgner/openpace/blob/master/appveyor.yml ) but nothing is working for me.   I can see the llvm compiler, but I really want Microsoft's.  What is the definitive way to get a Microsoft C compiler on my path in Appveyor?

Answer (score 0):

If you add something like this at any scripted stage (say `install` stage), you see whole bunch of those files

`cd c:\
dir /s cl.exe`

Here is very small part of my output:

 `Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
08/25/2016  11:13 PM           190,600 cl.exe
               1 File(s)        190,600 bytes
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64
08/25/2016  11:06 PM           229,000 cl.exe
               1 File(s)        229,000 bytes
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_arm
08/25/2016  11:06 PM           225,568 cl.exe
               1 File(s)        225,568 bytes
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_x86
08/25/2016  11:06 PM           229,664 cl.exe
               1 File(s)        229,664 bytes
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64
08/25/2016  11:13 PM           190,752 cl.exe
               1 File(s)        190,752 bytes
 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_arm`

Another option to investigate AppVeyor VM (if you cannot find answer [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#pre-installed-software)) is [RDP](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/).

Answer (score 0):

The way to I do it, is running `vcvarsall.bat`.
This has been the most reliable way to add the right compiler to the path.
(I also use this to set up the proper environment to compile with clang-cl.)

Example AppVeyor.yml:

```
image:
- Visual Studio 2015
- Visual Studio 2017

platform:
- x86
- x64

environment:
    VCVAR2015: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat'
    VCVAR2017: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat'

before_build:
- ps: |
    # ...example script to set the proper flags for vcvarsall ...
    # syntax: vcvarsall.bat [architecture] [platform_type] [winsdk_version] [-vcvars_ver=vcversion]
    $Architecture = $env:PLATFORM # simplified, works for x86 and x64
    if ("$env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE" -eq "Visual Studio 2015") {
      $env:VCVARSALL = "`"$env:VCVAR2015`" $Architecture"
    } else {
      $env:VCVARSALL = "`"$env:VCVAR2017`" $Architecture"
    }
- call %VCVARSALL%

build_script:
- cl
- link
```

It is also possible to call a specific version like `vcvarsamd64_x86.bat` but I prefer to set the flags in a script.

- Documentation on AppVeyor: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/lang/cpp/
- Documentation vcvarsall: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2015